# How to access a class defined in module B from module A

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Error message:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant FinancialFunctions::ComputationSteps::TwoBranchesPerPeriod::Strategy1
```

I'd like Rails to automatically look through the included Strategies module and see the class defined within it instead of just looking within TwoBranchesPerPeriod.

This is not a one-time problem and is part of a broader architecture restructuring. Solving this problem will help in many places throughout the codebase.

There are two specific solutions I'm *not* looking for:

- Having a `require` or `load` statement at the top of the file, as I want Rails autoloading to be the core solution for this problem and not have to require several files.
- Explicitly state the scope when initializing the class. I'm aware that simply calling `Strategies::Strategy1.new` will work, but this solution does not work for me because of the length of several classes. I'd like to simply define the dependencies at the top of the file with `include` statements, and have access to the methods/classes defined in the included modules.
- I'm open to `autoload` statements in a file such as strategies.rb but from what I've test this does not work either.

app/lib/financial_functions/computation_steps/two_branches_per_period.rb:

```
module FinancialFunctions
  module ComputationSteps
   module TwoBranchesPerPeriod
      include Strategies
      def a_method
        #The below line is resulting in the error
        # NameError: uninitialized constant FinancialFunctions::ComputationSteps::TwoBranchesPerPeriod::Strategy1
        a=Strategy1.new
      end
   end
  end
end
```

/app/lib/financial_functions/computation_steps/strategies/strategy1.rb:

```
module FinancialFunctions
  module ComputationSteps
   module Strategies
    class Strategy1
      def initialize
        puts "this should work"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: including or extending a module only copies methods, it doesn't do anything regarding classes. Is it too much typing to say `Strategies::Strategy1` instead?

Comment: `class` and `module` should be lowercase.

Comment: yes they are all lowercase, just a mistake in typing. @maxpleaner many of these class names are quite long and often they're more than 1 module "apart" which means several chained scopes/namespaces together. For readability purposes this is why I want to declare these long scopes even somewhere at the top of the file and have access below with just the method names

Comment: If you suggest explicitly including the name I'm fine with that. Can I ask you another question that gets to the root of the issue. I've had massive troubles with getting Rails to properly load/reload changes to files. So if I include a module, then if I change the method and make the request again, sometimes the changes to a method won't be seen or visible. Because of this I developed a bad habit of explicitly making numerous explicit load statements at the top of the class. Any suggestions on how to go about fixing this?? everything is under app/lib so it should be autoloaded

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely easier to be explicit, even if it's something like `Strategy1 = Strategies::Strategy1`. Regarding reloading of files, I'm sorry I don't remember offhand, there is certainly a way to do it though.

Comment: Why not look at the Zeitwerk gem (included in rails 6 by default) which handles all the autoloading for you. No questions asked. The only catch is that you have to carefully nest all the modules within folders matching the nesting of your modules. It saves you from huge headaches, with require statements (especially if you move modules around) but at the cost of autoloading. look into it here: https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to simply define the dependencies at the top of the file with
>   include statements, and have access to the methods/classes defined in
>   the included modules.

Your expectations are not realistic in Ruby. Ruby does not have a package system and  `includes` is not equivalent to `imports` in languages such as Python or ES6.

As stated in the comments by @maxpleaner includes only copies the methods of the module.

So to do this you would have to define new constants in the consuming class/module:

```
module FinancialFunctions
  module ComputationSteps
    module TwoBranchesPerPeriod
      include Strategies
      Strategy1 = ComputationSteps::Strategies::Strategy1

      def a_method
        Strategy1.new
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can do this dynamically through the `Module#included` hook:

```
module Foo
  module Bar
  end

  module Baz
  end

  def self.included(base)
    self.constants.each do |c|
      base.constant_set(c, self.constant_get(c))
    end
  end
end
```

```
module X
  includes Foo
end
```

```
irb(main):002:0> X::Bar
=> Foo::Bar
```

But aside from being an fun example of meta-programming I don't really think its that wise as the there is no way to handle namespace conflicts. You could also construct a makeshift equivalent of an imports construct:

```
module Importer
  def import(*constants, from:)
    constants.each do |c|
      const_set(c, from.const_get(c))
    end
  end
end
```

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    module A
    end
    module B
    end
  end
end
```

```
class Thing
  extend Importer
  import :A, :B, from: Foo::Bar
end
```

```
irb(main):001:0> Thing::A
=> Foo::Bar::A
irb(main):002:0> Thing::B
=> Foo::Bar::B
```

But this also smells like an example of fighting the language and will probably introduce more problems then it solves.